# Extra Line and Comma in String Issues

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have the following code that inputs a CSV file and then converts it and outputs a CSV file.  I am using FileHelper for CSV reading. I am having a couple problems with it. First, an extra line with field information is being inserted (see below). The second problem is that I have added double quotes so I can have a string in a cell that contains a comma; I can't find anything wrong with the formatting but it will not import into excel and only shows the double quotes and the first item. I have tried using the double quotation mark for escaping text option when importing into excel. The third problem is that some fields are blank and result in later offset of fields.

Second line of fields:

```
, base, 0, 0, 0, Product Name, Size, Brand, Gender, Type, SKU, Stock, Sí, "Photo1, Photo2, Photo3", Photo1, Photo1, Photo1
```

Code:

```
using System;
using FileHelpers;
using System.IO;

[DelimitedRecord(";")]
public sealed class StoreItems
{

[FieldOptional()]
public String Attribut;

[FieldOptional()]
public String ProductName;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Size;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Brand;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Type;

[FieldOptional()]
public String ParentSKU;

[FieldOptional()]
public String SKU;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Stock;

[FieldOptional()]
public String RetailEURO;

[FieldOptional()]
public String SuggestedsellEURO;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Weight;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Description;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Photo1;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Photo2;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Photo3;

[FieldOptional()]
public String Gender;

[FieldOptional()]
public String EAN13;
}

public class RunProgram
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(StoreItems));
        StoreItems[] res = engine.ReadFile("Presta.csv") as StoreItems[];

        Directory.CreateDirectory("Output");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@".\Output\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".csv");
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(sw);

        Console.WriteLine("_type, _product_websites, tax_class_id, _visibility, is_in_stock, name, taglia, manufacturer, gender, _attribute_set, sku, qty, use_external_images, external_gallery, " +
            "thumbnail_external_url, small_image_external_url, image_external_url");

        foreach(StoreItems item in res)
        {
            string newtype = null;
            int visibility = 0;

            if (item.Attribut == "Parent")
            {
                newtype = "Configurable";
                visibility = 4;
            }
            else if (item.Attribut == "Child")
            {
                newtype = "Simple";
                visibility = 1;
            }

            int isinstock;

            int stockint;

            try
            {
               stockint = Convert.ToInt32(item.Stock);
            }
            catch
            {
               stockint = 0;
            }

            if (stockint > 0)
            {
                isinstock = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                isinstock = 0;
            }


            Console.WriteLine(newtype + ", base, 0, " + visibility + ", " + isinstock + ", " + item.ProductName + ", " + item.Size + ", " +
                item.Brand + ", " + item.Gender + ", " + item.Type + ", " + item.SKU + ", " + item.Stock + ", Sí, " + @""""+item.Photo1+ ", "+item.Photo2+", "+item.Photo3+@"""" + ", " + item.Photo1 + ", " + item.Photo1 +
                ", " + item.Photo1);

        }



    }


}
```

Edit: I just realized that the second line is being added in from the reading of the input file. I just need to find a way to ignore the first line. The fields also no longer seem to be offsetting. Now just how to use commas in the csv?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second problem;

You don't have to use commas as a separator, you can use any character you want. So as a quick fix, why not change the ',' separator in your output to '|'.

If, of course, you also need to output '|' in your text, this is not going to help, but if not - quick fix to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

One problem; you have;

```
string newtype = null;
int visibility = 0;

if (item.Attribut == "Parent")
{
    newtype = "Configurable";
    visibility = 4;
}
else if (item.Attribut == "Child")
{
    newtype = "Simple";
    visibility = 1;
}
```

If `item.Attribut` is neither "Parent" or "Child" exactly, then `newtype` is not set. Hence why the first field in your example output is blank.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The files that I am working with will always have one of those, unless the field should be empty. So I use `newtype` for my first field and it returns blank if the original field is neither of those. As for your other answer, that is a great idea! I just have to check to make sure that the program that the file is going in to will accept that formatting.